# How do I make this array into a list using getElementById and innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-lists

I need to make the array 'places' display its contents in the list. My problem is my function. I know I'm not doing it right. Can anyone help? Do I need to use getElementsByTagName?

```html
<body>
      <header>
        <h1>
           Hands-on Project 3-3
        </h1>
      </header>

      <article>
        <h2>Scouting Locations</h2>
        <div id="results">
            <ul>
               <li id="item1"></li>
               <li id="item2"></li>
               <li id="item3"></li>
               <li id="item4"></li>
               <li id="item5"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
      <script>
   
      var places = ["Philadelphia", "New York", "Los Angles", "Austin", "Kansas City"];
    
      function processPlaces() {
       for (i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
        var listItem = "item" + (i + 1);
        document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = places[i]; 
      
       }
      }
    
      if (window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener("load", processPlaces, false);
      } else if (window.attachEvent) {
     window.attachEvent("onload", processPlaces);
      }
    
      </script>
      </body>
```

Comment: Change the commas to semicolons in your `for` loop:  `for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)`.

Comment: Also, make sure to declare all your variables.  You have not declared i, so it could stomp on a global variable.

Use element.textContent instead of element.innerHTML whenever possible. It's faster, since it doesn't have to parse tags or special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using commas `,` instead of semicolon `;` in your `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

Note: I've inserted the `var` keyword, because it's better to declare the variable inside the loop, avoiding the implicit declaration of `i` into the global context.

Comment: @Olympus if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as the accepted one by clicking on the `V` right below the upvote/downvote arrows. Look that doing that will also make you earn 2 reputation points! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could grab the containing div `results` and creating a `ul` like this `var locations = $('<ul>')` and then creating a function that  loops through you array and within each iteration creates a `li` and it's content then appends it to the ul, and finally at the end appends the ul to the container div. Here is a rough version of what that might look like in jQuery. Same concept in JS slightly different syntax.

```
var results = $('#results');
var list = $('<ul>');

function processPlaces() {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          var listItem = $('<li>');
          listItem.text(places[i]); 
          list.append(listItem);
      }
     results.append(list);
  }
```

this dynamic approach may be better so that as you add stuff to the array you do not need to go back to the html and manually add more `li`'s each time.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure and plain solution**:

One can access the list items through the id of the `<div>`:

```
<div id="results">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Access lists with `children`:

```
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var lists = results.children[0].children;
```

`Lists` is a **HTML collection** with all `<li>` elements.
Access **all** `<li>`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i += 1) {
    lists[i].innerHTML = places[i];
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/brqoxjvs/1/)